# Webservice called through jquery mobile not working in android web browser

Tags: android, jquery

I have built an application in Jquery Mobile Ajax and .Net Webservice which is quite good working in IE . but when we are using that in Android Tabs or Android Devices its not working.Why is it so ? does that does not support jquery or Webservice called by Jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the @doctype file. Replace XHTML to HTML5.